# Opigno Course Display Issue

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have a problem using Opigno. As you see in the screenshot below i have 2 field containers. goo.gl/qOVpji

The idea is that I can't find how to edit which field where will get.

I actually tried to create a different display, but whatever and however i change the fields in display tab of content types, this sidebar remains the same place and gathers in any field i create and try to display.
No matter how i do display it, it always displays this way.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So, in case somebody else had this issue, here's the response.

We have a file in opingo theme (themes/platon/template.php), ~ on the line 457 we have "function platon_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook)".

Starting from there, and ending up on line 488 - you will have the functions we need just to stop this strange grouping. Just commend those lines and in **content type** *display*  tab, create a group and divide them. This will work perfectly!

Hope i'll help anybody out!